# Counting Homogeneous Forms on Elliptic Curves

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, elliptic-curves

I'm trying to understand some argument that is being made regarding homogeneous forms on an elliptic curve. In order to do this, I need to understand how we determine the dimension of the space of homogeneous forms of fixed degree $d$ on the elliptic curve $E/\mathbb{Q}$ of rank $r$. I can't see anything online regarding this, and I'm not sure where to start myself.  Any advice on how to grasp a hold of this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this recently - it's relatively trivial actually. It simply corresponds to the fact that on a space of dimension $r$ there are at most $\binom{d+r-1}{r-1}$ homogenous functions of degree $d$. This can be seen by looking at homogenous polynomials of degree $d$ among $r$ variables.